# Weird behavior of keyboard events in Java

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keylistener

When I press `"Delete"` button on the keyboard, program gets three events - `KEY_PRESSED`, `KEY_TYPED`, and `KEY_RELEASED`. The problem is, in `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED`, parameter `"keyCode"` is set, but in the `KEY_TYPED` it is not (in fact, there no meaningful info in that event). With `F5` key, it is even funnier - `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED` are registered, but `KEY_TYPED` never occurs.

The listener was added via `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener()`. Using JDK 6.26.

What could be my problem?

EDIT:
Here are the events that happen when `Delete` key is pressed:

```
 java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=127,keyText=Delete,keyChar=Delete,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=119,primaryLevelUnicode=127,scancode=0] on javax.swing.JButton[,0,0,61x30,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@50f38cf0,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=javax.swing.ImageIcon@6ae2d0b2,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=SVG,defaultCapable=false]
 java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_TYPED,keyCode=0,keyText=Unknown keyCode: 0x0,keyChar=Delete,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN,rawCode=0,primaryLevelUnicode=127,scancode=0] on javax.swing.JButton[,0,0,61x30,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@50f38cf0,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=javax.swing.ImageIcon@6ae2d0b2,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=SVG,defaultCapable=false]
 java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=127,keyText=Delete,keyChar=Delete,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=119,primaryLevelUnicode=127,scancode=0] on javax.swing.JButton[,0,0,61x30,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@50f38cf0,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=javax.swing.ImageIcon@6ae2d0b2,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=SVG,defaultCapable=false]
```

Comment: What is the problem here? Did you check if this is the normal behaviour? If so can you not just have an if statement ignoring the event if it equals the KEY_TYPED if it doesn't have the information you need?

Comment: @Mike - my problem is that I really need to know, when user types Del or F5 on his keyboard.

Comment: Can you not get that information from the KEY_PRESSED keyCode?

Comment: usual questions: a) why do you need a keyListener  b) why do you need the global hammer? (both as opposed to keyBindings)

Comment: @kleopatra - I need global hammer because I do not want to bother about which component is focused when - I just need the global shortcuts in the program. But maybe I should look at keyBindings more closely.

Comment: global shortcuts sound like a use-case for keybindings :) Register with the rootPane's inputMap of type WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#KEY_TYPED)  `The "key typed" event. This event is generated when a character is entered. In the simplest case, it is produced by a single key press. Often, however, characters are produced by series of key presses, and the mapping from key pressed events to key typed events may be many-to-one or many-to-many.`

You are trying to get the F5 key which is probably not registered as a character being entered. By using the KEY_RELEASED you will consistently get the result you are looking for and the API is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 5):

- better would be implements [KeyBindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)
- part of keyboard are reserved Keys for built-in JComponent funcionality, more informations from @camickrs [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/)
- depends of reason(s) why you needed implents KeyListener, because for there are lots of another Listeners for various JComponent, that should be filtering or register text changes inside
- some of JComponent Models generated Events from Mouse and Keyboard input

Comment: +1 for Key Bindings. Rarely would you need to use a KeyListener for a requirement like this.

Answer (score 1):

Key typed events ALWAYS generate '0' as the key code. Look up the method getKeyChar() instead, or (as has been suggested) listen for keyReleased() instead.
getKeyChar(): http://goo.gl/ajH03